# Image Loss while transferring

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to send images from a C++ client application using libcurl, to a asmx webservice hosted in IIS. The issue is there are some images delivered to the server & most of them are lost , I am not able to figure out the reason for the same.Need help for the same.

Comment: Have you tried sending them directly from curl (not inside the C++ application)? Have you seen errors reported inside the web server?

Comment: No @Gerriet , I haven't

Comment: Figured out the issue, actually client was not able to send the data, in appropriate format as expected by the webservice, so the issue.